# Panel.add not instantly?

Tags: java, applet, panel

got some problems.

Built an applet that has to be used step-by-step. After each step, a button is clicked and the next step should be added into the GUI.

Problem: without zooming, the added content doesn't get visible. in a application you can workaround with scaling the window size, but in an applet I wasn't able to solve that problem.

Thanks

EDIT:

actually, it looks smth like this:

```
 Panel cp = new Panel(new GridLayout(0,2));
 Panel Block1 = new Panel(new GridLayout(2,2));
 Panel Block1 = new Panel(new GridLayout(2,2));
  ...
```

init

```
 public void init()
  {  

   buildBlock1();
   buildBlock2();


    add(cp);
    cp.setVisible(true);
  }
```

adding some empty panels here, those who will get filled afterwards

```
private void buildBlock1()
{
Block1.add(panel1);
Block1.add(panel2);
Block1.add(panel3);
Block1.add(panel4);

cp.add(Block1);
}
```

button actionlistener

```
private void generatePanel1()
 {
  //adding some Components to the subpanel of Block1, which is a subpanel of cp.
 Panel1.add(...);
 cp.repaint();
 cp.validate();
 }
```

Comment: Can you provide some code? It would be helpful with a small but complete example.

Comment: Are you calling `repaint()` after the button is pressed? Sounds like that could be your problem.

Comment: actually I dont even use a paint() method, just converted my application to an aplet. Is this needed?
UPDATE: not even with repaint() it's updating well

Comment: 1) *"converted my application to an aplet"* If the frame based app. works, launch it from a link using [Java Web Start](http://stackoverflow.com/tags/java-web-start/info).  It will not only be easier for you, but a better experience for the user. 2) For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). 3) **Use a `CardLayout`.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Now I don't have any code that I can check but adding (and removing) components to a container normally often needs to be "validated". So try

```
panel.add(...); 
panel.revalidate();
```

---

API docs for [`JComponent.revalidate()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/javax/swing/JComponent.html#revalidate%28%29):

> Validates this container and all of its subcomponents.
>
> Supports deferred automatic layout.
>
> Calls invalidate and then adds this component's validateRoot to a list of components that need to be validated. Validation will occur after all currently pending events have been dispatched. In other words after this method is called, the first validateRoot (if any) found when walking up the containment hierarchy of this component will be validated. By default, JRootPane, JScrollPane, and JTextField return true from isValidateRoot.
>
> This method will automatically be called on this component when a property value changes such that size, location, or internal layout of this component has been affected. This automatic updating differs from the AWT because programs generally no longer need to invoke validate to get the contents of the GUI to update. The validate method is used to cause a container to lay out its subcomponents again. It should be invoked when this container's subcomponents are modified (added to or removed from the container, or layout-related information changed) after the container has been displayed.

Comment: it kinda works fine when I rune the applet using eclipse, in FF13 it just doesm't update.